# OneDrive for Business for Mac, spinning circle freezes laptop for 2 minutes. Possibly due to .ms-one-stub files.

Tags: onedrive-for-business, mac-os-x

Note: This is not my computer. I do not have access to the computer having the issue.

> I’ve been having odd problems with my mac today and I think it’s
>   related to One Drive. I’m seeing these .ms-one-stub files in my One
>   Drive all of a sudden (see attached pic), and it’s not syncing on my
>   mac as of around 3p or 4p yesterday. I get the “spinning wheel” when I
>   try to click on the one drive logo in my top menu bar. Then my
>   keyboard stops working and doesn’t respond until the spinning wheel
>   goes away.

I've looked into this, and it appears as if these files are just normal stub files that shouldn't cause issues. I have yet to find anything about these files causing anyone else issues. Anyways, he sent me an update explaining that he reinstalled one drive for business, that the problem was temporarily gone, then came back again.

I'm guessing it is just his file system attempting to sync with OneDrive / sharepoint. I do not have access to his computer and I have been put in charge of fixing his issue. Any words of wisdom would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bulletin in the Office 365 portal right now that looks to be affecting you:

> SP66473 - SharePoint Features - Restoring service Restoring service -
>   Jun 2, 2016 12:22 PM
>
> Current Status: The initial fix improved service availability and
>   we're implementing additional fixes to completely restore service.
>   Once the deployments are complete, we'll monitor the environment to
>   ensure that service is restored.
>
> User Impact: Users may observe that the OneDrive for Business sync
>   client for Mac OS X stops responding when a background task attempts
>   to synchronize files. Users can force quit the application and remove
>   it from the list of login items to avoid interruptions due to client
>   crashes while the fix is being deployed. While we're focused on
>   remediation, users can access their files by using the OneDrive for
>   Business website.
>
> Scope of Impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our
>   analysis indicates that this issue is specific to Mac users who have
>   the OneDrive for Business sync client installed.
>
> Start Time: Thursday, May 26, 2016, at 4:02 AM UTC
>
> Preliminary Root Cause: An unexpected problem caused impact to occur
>   during a regularly scheduled systems update.
>
> Next Update by: Friday, June 3, 2016, at 5:00 PM UTC